# Combine two SSRS reports and present as one

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have two reports A.rdl and B.rdl. When I run A.rdl, I also want to stitch B.rdl to the output, so it's like a single report. One way to achieve this is to use B as subreport in A (adjust page break and all), however, the subreport doesn't preserve its header and footer. I'm trying to combine both report into one with their own header and footer. Is there a way to do this either using subreport or any C# code to do it through reportviewer?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this (If I understand it correctly)  is to develop a new report C, containing only the common header and the other subrebports A and B without headers. Like this example:
[Report_C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4tQn.jpg)